# What exactly means this expression found in a .NET view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am very new in **.NET** and I have the following doubt about these expression that I am finding in some views.

I have a view like this:

```
@model Vidly_v2.ViewModels.NewCustomerViewModel
@{
    /**/

    ViewBag.Title = "New";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>New Customer</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Customers"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Birthdate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Birthdate, "{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"), "Select Membership Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter) Subscribed to Newsletter?
        </label>
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

As you can see in this vire I am using this **model object**:

```
@model Vidly_v2.ViewModels.NewCustomerViewModel
```

Into this view I use this model object in this way:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

that simply render this HTML code:

```
<label for="Customer_Name">Name</label>
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Name must be a string with a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255" data-val-required="The Name field is required." id="Customer_Name" name="Customer.Name" value="" type="text">
```

related to this model object property.

My doubt is: what exactly is and what represents this expression?

```
m => m.Customer.Name
```

I think that **m** means **model object** (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion) but I can't understand the meaning and the exact use of this expression.

Comment: `Customer` means the property name which defines navigation property to other class (e.g. `Customer`) and `Name` means target property which contained inside navigation property. You should add the model class to help explain this further.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers

Comment: Its a lambda expression.Think of it as _for my model, which I will refer to as `m`, give me the `Name` property of the `Customer` property_

Answer (score 0):

The expression is called a lambda expression.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

The HtmlHelpers extension methods accept a function with a model and a property as a value, as per the example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LabelExtensions_LabelFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_String_System_Object_